# Join Pandas dataframe columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Dataframe A

| cid | country | a_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | US | 100 |
| 1 | UK | 200 |
| 2 | CN | 300 |
| 3 | US | 400 |
| 4 | UK | 500 |

Dataframe B

| cid | country | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | US | 600 |
| 5 | UK | 700 |
| 6 | CN | 800 |
| 7 | US | 900 |
| 8 | UK | 1000 |

Left Join Dataframe B with A. Join based on country names and cid where cid Condition: cid of B - 4 = cid of A

Result DF:

| cid | country | price | a_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | US | 600 | 100 |
| 5 | UK | 700 | 200 |
| 6 | CN | 800 | 300 |
| 7 | US | 900 | 400 |
| 8 | UK | 1000 | 500 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a new column in B with the calculations and join by this column instead of the original. Then you can drop the column if you don't want it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
df_all = pd.merge(df_b,df_a[['country','a_price']],on='country', how='left')
```

Edit: (I just found you said **cid of b -4 = cid of A**, so please try below instead)

```
df_b["cid"] = df_b["cid"].apply(lambda x: x - 4)
df_all=pd.merge(df_b,df_a,  how='left', left_on=['cid','country'], 
right_on = 'cid','country')

df_all = df_all[df_all['a_price'].notna()]
df_all["cid"] = df_all["cid"].apply(lambda x: x + 4)
```

Comment: There are repetitive countries in the dataset.

Comment: @Codelearner I just edit my code